# How to run serve with iis express using cmd in dotnet5 webapi?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have web-api application with dotnet5.

When I run the application using cmd: `dotnet run --project MyProj` or `dotnet watch --project MyProj`, it serves the application in `localhost:5001` or `localhost:5000`.

But when I open visual studio and launch the application using the button (iis express) it opens in a different address.

[image]

How do I serve it with iis express in the cmd? What is the command for it?

Comment: Hows your launchSettings.json file looks like? Beause, your application would run based on your launchSettings.json. Could you please include that within the question. May I know why do you want to run IIS express by command line?